# Facebook Login button not showing in "rwd" theme, but working fine in "default" theme in Magento 1.9

Tags: rwd, dashboard

I installed Magento 1.9 and the theme "rwd" came along with it. I changed all the categories and products. Then I installed a Facebook Login extension, which works fine with the "default" theme, but when I activate the "rwd" theme the Facebook Login button doesn't get displayed on any page.
Also, could anyone assist me to clear up the Dashboard stats, which shows a lot of total sales? I got hold of some mysql statements, but in Magento 1.9 the table names don't match.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you might have installed Belgv facebook login extension. YOu are not able to see the facebook login button because you haven't copied the template file to your theme rwd.

1) Goto design->frontend->default->Layout and design->frontend->default->template

2) copy the file for the extension into your theme. If  you are using Belgv facebook free the name might be `facebookfree` for template folder and `facebookfree.xml` for layout.

**[EDIT]**

If the above solution doesn't work. You can add the code below in `customer/form/login.phtml`

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign in with facebook') ?>" class="button fb_button_ps signface-btn" onclick="return fblogin();" ><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Sign in with facebook > ') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: If it helped you mark the answer as accepted, so others can get help from it.

Comment: Dexter, thank you for your quick response. Yes, I am using BELVG Facebook Free extension. I just checked the folders you mentioned. There is already a file "facebookfree.xml" in RWD Layout folder, and a folder "facebookfree" in RWD Template folder.

Comment: have you done all settings in admin and have created facebook API key and all? you wont see the button unless you create a facebook app and insert the key over there

Comment: Shall I replace them again?

Comment: if done.. you can try replacing them once again.. i think it should work..

Comment: I have created the Facebook App and done all the required settings. The Facebook Login button is displayed when I change the Package to "default" in Magento Admin, and the login works like a charm. But the button doesn't show up when I use the "rwd" package.

Comment: in that case you should try manually putting this code in login form `<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign in with facebook') ?>" class="button fb_button_ps signface-btn" onclick="return fblogin();" ><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Sign in with facebook > ') ?></span></span></button>`

Comment: which is the file I have to edit for the "login form" you mentioned?

Comment: you have to put the above code manually in customer/form/login.phtml

Comment: Wonderful... now, the "Login with Facebook" button is coming up in the "Account" drop down list on the pages. Can we get the box alongside "Account" and "Cart" on the page itself?

Comment: Yes, you need to make changes in xml and template file..

Comment: Sorry, I was offline all evening. I will try to make changes in the XML and Template Files. Can you help me with the other request in my original query, for clearing up the Dashboard Stats in Magento 1.9? Any SQL script or any option in Magento Admin Panel?

Comment: please ask it in another question and mark this as close.. we need to make the answer percentange above 80% for this website